# .htaccess ErrorDocument issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, errordocument

Problem with custom error pages.
My server root is "C:\www" and error pages are in "C:\www\errors".
So I put a .htaccess file in "C:\www" with following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

This works for anything in "mysite.net". But I also have subdirectories like "first.mysite.net", "second.mysite.net" and so on, and .htaccess from root doest work there. It's searching for "errors" folder in these subfolders and return the default 404 page.

I've tried this:

```
ErrorDocument 500 C:/www/errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 500 C:\www\errors\500.html
```

Doesn't work.

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://mysite.net/errors/500.html
```

This works, but it makes a redirect and I don't want this. I want the browser to keep adress line the same.

Can anyone make this clear for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are subdomains with seperate virtualhost definitions you need to check virtualhost definitions and AllowOverride settings for those subdomains. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride and change AllowOverride setting as needed.

Comment: I don't know much about virtualhosts, I only made my server to use any folder as a subdomain.